# Error Deserializing XML due to malformed XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

So I have a fairly simple RSS that I'm downloading and then deserializing using XmlSerializer.  For some odd reason that I cannot figure out nor after reporting the issue the owner of the RSS hasn't fixed after months.

This is the malformed item in the RSS:

```
<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">TopicID_441307</guid>
    <link>https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=441307</link>
    <author>Malycia Kiss</author>
    <title>WTB Freighter / JF Pilot with PI</title>
    <description>&lt;a href=https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&amp;m=5976122#post5976122 &gt;Go to last post&lt;/a&gtgt; by</description>
    <a10:updated>2015-08-18T17:33:40Z</a10:updated>
</item>
```

The malformed section is in the description element due to the &gtgt, which is just supposed to be &gt - again, I have no idea why their RSS puts the extra characters there.

When deserializing, I get an error:

```
Unexpected node type EntityReference. ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content. Line 3231, position 130.
```

The questions!

1. If those sanitized characters are contained within a proper element , why does it care if there is a malformed URL encoded string?
2. Is this because the XmlSerializer is trying to revert these encoded values back to their original character?
3. What is the best way to handle this?  Keep in mind that I've only ever run into this type of issue once or twice on each RSS feed and only for &gt and &lt encodings - so maybe just a simple find/replace?

Sorry if I used the wrong terms when explaining this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with HTML content inside an XML element.

It looks properly encoded and decoding should be automatic. But your fragment is indeed "malformed", and that is a condition most Xml readers refuse to deal with - they just throw an error.

> 3. What is the best way to handle this?

You will have to repair the XML before loading it. In this case,

```
rssText = rssText.Replace("/a&gtgt;" , "/a&gt;");
```

should do it. The Value of `<description>` should then read as valid HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to 'turn off' this automatic decoding of HTML during a deserialization process?  I'm just puzzled as to why it automatically does it and would rather throw an error in place of just returning the string.

Comment: What does the /a in the beginning of the search string represent?

Comment: `/a` is from the closing `</a>` tag. The original text `&gtgt;` is just wrong - it looks like an error in the generator. Not uncommon in the RSS world.

Comment: There is no "decoding of HTML" going on here. Entity references (&entity;) are XML. If you want the resulting HTML to include an entity reference, then you need to double-escape it. (e.g. &amp;gt;)

Comment: @j__m - not clear what you are on about. The HTML is XML encode but then `&gtgt;` is just not valid.

Comment: @HenkHolterman "decoding of HTML" was a direct quote that indicated what I was responding to. If you didn't use those words, then it's not about you.